# How to send data from one webApplication to another

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, httprequest

I have two web applications in two different server.I want send some data in header or request to other web application.How can I do that, please help me.

Comment: It is based on the data your are sending, [Refer](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Get_vs_Post)

Answer (score 5):

You can pass data by many means:

1. by making http request from your app:

   ```
   URLConnection conn = new URL("your other web app servlet url").openConnection();
   // pass data using conn. Then on other side you can have a servlet that will receive these calls.
   ```
2. By using JMS for asynchronous communication.
3. By using webservice (SOAP or REST)
4. By using RMI
5. By sharing database between the apps. So one writes to a table and the other reads from that table
6. By sharing file system file(s)...one writes to a file the other reads from a file.
7. You can use socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient can help

http://hc.apache.org/index.html

> Apache HttpComponents
>
> The Apache HttpComponents™ project is responsible for creating and
>   maintaining a toolset of low level Java components focused on HTTP and
>   associated protocols.

Answer (score 0):

One web application is functioning as the client of the other. You can use the `org.apache.http` library to create your HTTP client code in Java. How you will do this depends on a couple of things:

1. Are you using http or https?
2. Does the application you are sending data to have a REST API?
3. Do you have a SOAP based web service?

If you have a SOAP based web service, then creating a Java client for it is very easy. If not, you could do something like this and test the code in a regular Java client before trying to run it in the web application.

```
 import org.apache.http.client.utils.*;
 import org.apache.http.*; 
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.*;

  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  try {
     URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
     builder.setHost("yoursite.com").setPath(/appath/rsc/);
     builder.addParameter("user", username);
     builder.addParameter("param1", "SomeData-sentAsParameter");
     URI uri = builder.build();
     HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
     System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
     if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
     } else {
        log(Level.SEVERE, "Server returned HTTP code "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
     }
  } catch (java.net.URISyntaxException bad) {
     System.out.println("URI construction error: " + bad.toString());
  }
```